# get ethernet to work on windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I've been a Linux-only user for the past 10 years, but I need to use Windows for something work-related. I'm having issues with getting ethernet to work on Windows (but it works just fine on pop os, my current distro of choice). I have a tuxedo Polaris 15 AMD. My ethernet port is recognized as "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" under windows. I have tried installing the official drivers from my laptop OEM's website as well as from Realtek. I even tried to use one of those drive download softwares, all to no avail. Windows fails and marks the device status as the following:

```
The driver for this device has been blocked from starting because it is known to have problems with Windows. Contact the hardware vendor for a new driver. (Code 48)

Click 'Check for solutions' to send data about this device to Microsoft and to see if there is a solution available.
```

When I look at the events I can see the following information:

```
Device PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_11001D05&REV_15\01000000684CE00000 had a problem starting.

Driver Name: oem33.inf
Class Guid: {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Service: rt640x64
Lower Filters: 
Upper Filters: 
Problem: 0x30
Problem Status: 0xC0000022
```

I apologize but I'm really not familiar with how Windows works anymore, what would be the next debugging steps? The device does not show under the adapter options in the network control panel or anything.

Comment: As a (temp) work around you could use a USB-Ethernet-Adapter, you can get one around $10. Might be the easier then to get the onboard adapter to work.

Comment: Normally, the drivers for RealTek should be included in Windows. I would uninstall the device (launch device manager, right-click on device, uninstall), uninstall the driver(s) you downloaded to ensure they cause no harm, then restart the PC. The correct driver should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You require drivers for Windows 10 - those for 8.x and 7 won't work. If they're not included in Win10 you can get them here:

https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software